# How do I look for word context for all files not just one in a directory with python?

Tags: python, glob

im new to python and trying to use my code to understand patterns/context of csv files that have text.My code is able to do this for one file at time. I want it to loop through multiple csv files in a directory and get me the context

```
 import pandas as pd
    def search_multiple_strings_in_file(file_name, list_of_strings):
        """Get line from the file along with line numbers, which contains any string from the list"""
        line_number = 0
        list_of_results = []
        # Open the file in read only mode
        with open("Sandrasales.csv", 'r') as read_obj:
            # Read all lines in the file one by one
            for line in read_obj:
                line_number += 1
                # For each line, check if line contains any string from the list of strings
                for string_to_search in list_of_strings:
                    if string_to_search in line:
                        # If any string is found in line, then append that line along with line number in list
                        list_of_results.append((string_to_search, line_number, line.rstrip()))
     
        # Return list of tuples containing matched string, line numbers and lines where string is found
        return list_of_results
    
    # search for given strings in the file 'sample.txt'
    
    
        matched_lines = search_multiple_strings_in_file('SandraSales.csv', ['renewal','provision','annual limit'])
         
        print('Total Matched lines : ', len(matched_lines))
        for elem in matched_lines:
            print('Word = ', elem[0], ' :: Line Number = ', elem[1], ' :: Line = ', elem[2])
```

Lets say my folder/ directory is C:\Users\jj\Desktop\analysis where all the csv files are.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
my_path = 'C:\Users\jj\Desktop\analysis'
for f in listdir(mypath):
    if f.endswith('.csv'):
        search_multiple_strings_in_file(f, list_of_strings)
```